# Text does not move to next line for WMD

Tags: html, css, markdown, wmd

I am using WMD for my textarea form and for some reason the text inside the preview box does not wrap once the text inside the text area continues to the next line.

```
<div class='wmd-preview'>
</div>
```

Is there a solution for this?

The WMD that I am talking about is the one that is used by Stack Overflow, http://wmd-editor.com/.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot or something?  To me, this sounds like expected behaviour (wrapping in the `<textarea>` shouldn't affect its value).

Comment: Either post your solution as an answer or delete your question.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, please can u let me know how you fixed this? I have the same problem.

Comment: me too! Let us know what you did

Comment: omg sorry guys, i think i did it with CSS word-wrap attribute.. I forgot how I did it exactly